# When is the direct comparison test not applicable? Vs Limit comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the DCT inapplicable with the harmonic series? I'm a bit confused as to their limitations, I prefer the DCT to the LCT it's easier, but I fear using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The direct and limit comparison tests only require that the terms be nonnegative and real-valued. You do have to be able to perform the tests, though. For the harmonic series in particular, the comparison test works, [as shown here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test).

Summing $2^k$ terms, $$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}\right) +  \left(\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8}\right) \dots > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}\right) + \dots$$

When summing $2^k$ terms, the second series is equal to $1 + \frac{k}{2}$, which diverges. Because the harmonic sum is larger, it must diverge as well.

There is also a version for **absolute** convergence, which allows for negative terms, as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_series).